# If statement matching string and user arguments

Tags: perl, if-statement, arguments

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to validate user input that matches a string followed by user arguments, it always goes to my else statement.

```
elsif ($user_input eq "sort by" && $ARGV[2])
    {
            print"this is working";
            #use arguments to sort by user command
            print $ARGV[2], "\n\n\n";

    }
    else #user validation
    {
            print "Error, please re-enter command \n\n";
            &Menu;
    }`
```

Comment: Are you forgetting to `chomp` user input?

Comment: If you want to glue strings together, use the concatenation operator `.`, as in `$user_input eq "sort by " . $ARGV[2]`. (Note the space after `by`.)

Comment: Please tell us what input you've tried that is yielding the unexpected results and how `$user_input` is getting populated.

Comment: If a program like that does not work as expected then consider adding some code to help you (and future users of your program) understand what is happening and what is wrong. The error clause might have be written as `print "Error, I do not understand the command \"$user_input\" with argument \"$ARGV[2]\". Please try again."`. Note the double quotes around the two interpolated variables to show _exactly_ what is being checked. The `\"$ARGV[2]\"` part of the print assumes that the value is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Params::Validate package available on CPAN. Quoting an example on the page

```
 validate(
        @_,
        { foo => { regex => qr/^\d+$/ } }
    );
```

You can use this to validate the input argument against a particular regex. There are also other useful checks Params::Validate can do for you.

**[Params::Validate](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Params-Validate-1.07/lib/Params/Validate.pm)**

Answer (score 1):

```
elsif ( my ($sort_by_what) = $user_input =~ /^sort by (\w+)\z/ ) {
    print "ok, I'll sort by $sort_by_what\n";
}
```

(use something other than \w+ to match your "x" if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, Is it that you want to check the string validation and user arguments independent of each other . You are using a short circuit and operation "&&" , so the moment it encounters a first false , it stops checking for the rest of the expression . Does that help you ?

Comment: I apologize for being vague. What I need for the if statement to do is match user input to be "sort by x", where x is the user argument and can be anything.

Comment: you can use a string concatenation operator , " . " , Try this 

elsif ($user_input eq "sort by " . $ARGV[2])

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
elsif ($user_input eq "sort by" && $ARGV[2])
```

by:

```
elsif( defined($ARGV[2]) and ($user_input eq "sort by $ARGV[2]") )
```